# Firebase Security Rules Private User Data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying these security rules from the docs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart#sample-rules):

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want the user to be able to read and write to their node under users and no-one else can access their information.

My data structure is like this:
Under users I store user information under their Facebook UID.

```
myfirebase
users
-<facebookUID>
->user info stored here
-<facebookUID>
->user info stored here
-<facebookUID>
->user info stored here
```

In my code I query the database by:

```
var userinformation = firebase.database().ref("users/" + <facebookUID>).on("value",function(snapshot) {

//...do stuff here

});
```

In simulator it works if I query the node: "users/" + facebookUID

But when I run code nothing returns.

So I'm guessing its something to do with the security rules cannot be a filter or something....like because I have no rules to access /users the access to their node returns false and no access is allowed. But if I allow access to users then because of the cascade then anyone can access anyone else's data.

So how can I fix this?

I tried looking at other's questions but can't work it out.

UPDATE - Some photos

[image: firebase structure]

[image: security rules]

Comment: The location you're querying seems fine. You're not trying to filter data, so are unlike to be hitting the "rules are not filters" that you mention. But where does `<facebookUID>` come from? Are you sure it has been initialized when you attach the listener?

Comment: Thanks for your help. By listener do you mean the .on call? That should be fine because when .read and .write is set to true on root the code works fine and I have access.

Ill add some photos to my original post

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen any chance you could fork this https://github.com/rhroyston/firebase-auth and add an 'admin approval' method to the bottom of the .js file (it would really help me, and I think others?)  You're the man.  ...BTW this is the only way I know to reach you. Hope you don't mind.  Something like approveUser(uid,'gold') / approveUser(uid,'bronze').  a multi-level admin?

Comment: I found the solution which was my mistake in the first place:

I thought that if a user logs in with Facebook that the auth.uid value in the security rules would be the facebook id, but no the facebook id is different to the auth.id in the firebase return object on login.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be misunderstanding how Firebase works. When you call `on()` is doesn't return any data. Instead, it starts listening for the data and calls you when that data is available and then it changes. So you need to handle the data in the callback:

```
firebase.database().ref("users/" + <facebookUID>).on("value",function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

This means that you cannot write your code in the usual "first get the user information, then do xyz with the user information" fashion. Instead you should frame the code as "start synchronizing the user information, then when the user information is available do xyz with it".

In the snippet above that "xyz" is logging the info, but you could just as easily update your UI. The important thing is that the code that does "xyz" must be inside the callback, because that's the only place where the user information is available (and up to date).

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need a rule farther out, i.e. not so nested.  You need to define a rule to allow r/w or it's gonna fail.  I hope I understood your question...?

Comment: ill try this and let you know

Answer (score 0):

You could also do the restriction on the javascript side by storing a list of branched paths that the user has access too under his or her user info branch. This would also encapsulate the user from everything else that he has no permissions to use or edit. I don't know how it would be done in javascript but I have done it in android. hope this helps.